# Docker windows - change php.ini

Tags: php, windows, docker

i'm using Docker on my Windows machine and I've build a docker-compose file which builds a php image out of a Dockerfile.

docker-compose.yml:

```
php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
    networks:
      - test
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
COPY ./php/php.ini /usr/local/lib
```

As you can see, I'm trying to copy my own php.ini file to the /usr/local/lib folder of my php image. I'm not sure if thats the correct path for the image at all but also, the php.ini file i'm trying to copy is from a php version for windows. The php7.2-fpm-alpine image is a linux version of php. I'm not sure if the php.ini file looks the same on windows and linux. However, my goal is it to increase the file size limit of files i'm trying to pass to php from my frontend (I'm doing a Video Upload)

I've tried several things, that copy was my last last attempt until now. I'm not quite sure what else I can try.

The problem is, whatever I do, the settings for the max_file_size are not confirmed. There is still the error, that the file is to big. i don't know if the php.ini file will be processed at all

Does anyone has a idea?

Comment: Hi huhaproblem, so what _is_ the problem. You don't really state it...

Comment: Some hints: examine the output of `phpinfo()`, it should tell you which INI file is in use by the current PHP installation (along with the full path). Make your changes in the INI file shipped with your target PHP installation, i.e. copy it out to somewhere, amend it, then instruct Docker to copy it back to the appropriate location.

Comment: You didn't copy your `php.ini` to the right location. Simple as that. Also your entire `build` section is unnecessary as those are default settings.

Comment: and where is the right location? :D

Comment: and yes, i'm still learning what docker belongs

Comment: Okay found it. the right path is /usr/local/etc/php - Now I've got several extention errors but thats another problem. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thing is to play with docker you must understand a lot of OS stuff, that's why a developer which masters it is called devops.

As a summary you first have to know what you install, in your case php:7.2-fpm-alpine, which you can find details for in the build on github: https://github.com/docker-library/php/tree/master/7.2

Reaching to the dockerfile and looking for php.ini you'll find this line :

```
ENV PHP_INI_DIR /usr/local/etc/php
```

But anyways you will almost always have to connect into your container to verify things or test stuff and also because it's always faster.

So the following command will help you much :

```
winpty docker-compose exec php //bin//bash
```

winpty is necessary on Windows, as the double slashes, at least if you use Git for Windows as terminal, I don't know about others.
"php" is the name of your entry in your docker-compose file.

And finally if you are beginning with docker etc I recommend to use mod-php with apache which is easier to setup than php-fpm with nginx, considering php-fpm with apache makes no sense.